# Refractor a function call

Tags: javascript

I am working on an API call in pure Javascript and I hit a section of code that i want to refractor The code is something like this

```
function getStart(city, lat, long, response) {
  const latDir = lat[lat.length - 1];
  const latVal = lat.slice(0, -1);

  const latMinVal = latVal - 15 < 0 ? 0 : latVal - 15;
  const latMaxVal = latVal + 15 > 90 ? 90 : latVal + 15;

  const longDir = long[long.length - 1];
  const longVal = long.slice(0, -1);

  const longMinVal = longVal - 15 < 0 ? 0 : longVal - 15;
  const longMaxVal = longVal + 15 > 180 ? 180 : longVal + 15;

  response = response.data;
  console.log(response);

  for (let i = 0; response && i < response.length; i++) {
    if (
      response[i][4] === latDir &&
      response[i][6] === longDir &&
      response[i][3] >= latMinVal &&
      response[i][3] <= latMaxVal &&
      response[i][5] >= longMinVal &&
      response[i][5] <= longMaxVal
    ) {
      const latRes = `${response[i][3]}${latDir}`;
      const longRes = `${response[i][5]}${longDir}`;
      const data = {
        e: response[i][1],
        lat: latRes,
        long: longRes,
        city: city
      };
      return data;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Is there any way to create a shorter version of this?

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, what we do here is review working code that you have written and provide tips on how to improve that code. The statement `The code is something like this` indicates this is not the exact working code that you have written and that would make the question off-topic for at least 2 reasons. 1) It isn't the actual working code. 2) It is not clear that you wrote the code. Please read [How do I ask a good question?(https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We need to know *what the code is intended to achieve*. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question, including a title that summarises the *purpose* of the code. We want to know **why** much more than **how**. The more you tell us about [what your code is for](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1226), the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  The title needs an [edit] to simply [**state the task**](//meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/2436), rather than your concerns about the code.

Answer (score 2):

Not really shorter, but something can be done to make it more readable.

#### Do some cleanup

Is

```
console.log(response)
```

really needed after the debugging is done?

#### Validate data before processing

You're checking for `response` not being falsy on every loop. Probably you should check it first and only then proceed to all other actions. This

```
if(!response.data)
    return null;
```

on the beginning will make the function longer, but the purpose will be much clearer.

#### Use deconstruction

I guess latVal is not exactly what to you want it to be (but still JavaScript allows some operations with wrong types, so the code can still be working-ish). Try

```
const [latVal, latDir] = lat
const [longVal, longDir] = long
```

instead.

#### Use min and max to limit values

This looks obvious when you know it, but somehow many developers misses it:

```
const latMinVal = Math.max(0, latVal - 15)
```

does the same and is much more readable.

#### Consider using `for - of`

If the `response` is validated,

```
for(const line of response)
```

or something like that can be better then using response[i] every time. You can also use decomposition here:

```
for(const [_1, respName, _2, respLat, respLatDir, respLong, lespLongDir] of response)
```

#### Complex interval comparisons look better with less sign only

```
  latMinVal <= response[i][3] && response[i][3] <= latMaxVal
```

is the best you can do to immitate mathematical/pythonic `latMinVal <= response[i][3]  <= latMaxVal`